# django validar cpf e tratar erro

Tags: django

Estou usando o BRCPFField do pacote localflavors para validar o CPF em um form, está funcionando, o problema é que no template quando digito um CPF não válido aparece aquela página de erro do django, eu queria apenas que fosse exibida uma mensagem e a pessoa poderia alterar o campo novamente... Qual a melhor forma pra fazer isso?

```
# form:

class ClienteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    cpf = BRCPFField()

    class Meta:
        model = Cliente
        fields = ('nome', 'cpf', 'celular', 'tel_fixo', 'email', 'end', 'data_cadastro')

# view:

def cadastrar_cliente(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cliente = form.save()
            cliente.save()
            return redirect('/calcados/', {})
    else:
        form = ClienteForm()
        return render(request, 'calcados/cadastrar.html', {'form': form})

# template:

{% extends 'calcados/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
{% endblock%}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando colocar um `else` para carregar a página novamente com o formulário caso haja erro:

```
def cadastrar_cliente(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cliente = form.save()
            cliente.save()
            return redirect('/calcados/', {})
        else:
            # caso o formulario tenha erro:
            return render(request, 'calcados/cadastrar.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ClienteForm()
        return render(request, 'calcados/cadastrar.html', {'form': form})
```

Você ainda poderia fazer assim:

```
def cadastrar_cliente(request):
    form = ClienteForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()                
            return redirect('/calcados/', {})     
    # retorna a pagina com form vazio ou com erros:       
    return render(request, 'calcados/cadastrar.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: deu certo, obrigado :)

Comment: De nada. Se achar que a resposta atendeu sua questão, pode aceitar ela como resposta marcando ao lado :)